# linq to entity filter after groupby caluse

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

What i want to achieve is simple thing like this using linq to entity. I want to filter the country id **only after** group by and select clause. However, i can't seem to achieve this simple linq. Applying filtering before group by will results in different key value produce, which is not something that i would expect. The key value that results before groupby is needed.

To put is simple of what i would like to achieve:

Get the key value (r.Key) of certain CountryID

Table:
ID CountryID 
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  2
5  1
6  3

```
_db.TableA.GroupBy(q => q.CountryID).Select(r => r.Key).Where(q => q.CountryID == 2)
```

Comment: You group by `CountryID`, so the `Key` of each group is simply `CountryID`. You could use `_db.TableA.GroupBy(q => q.CountryID).Where(grp => grp.Key == 2).Select(grp => grp.Key)`, but it would just result in `{2}`. You're question is unclear.

Comment: i would like to get the key value back based on country id from _db.TableA.GroupBy(q => q.CountryID).Select(r => r.Key)., not get the key based on key

Comment: So with `Key` you mean `ID`?

Comment: How are the values different when filtering before and after grouping? Conceptually, I can't imagine this.